# QTextDocument Newline handling and eliding

Tags: qt, qtextdocument

I am using [QTextdocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) and in my text there are "\n" for new line characters but QTextDocument is not handling it and it shows it as plain 1 line .
Is there any way we can make it handle "\n" as new line character, along with that I need eliding also.
So whenever any text is there after line break it should show "..."

E.g. 
This
is
the
Sample

Currently [QTextdocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) removed line breaks and shows it as "This is the sample"
2nd issue is for eliding Now suppose only 1 line is visible it should show it as "This..."
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

`QTextDocument` holds formatted text, so you can use `<br>` html tag for a new line and set it's content using  `QTextDocument::setHtml`.

Also you cab use `QTextDocument::setTextWidth` to set a specific width for text in the document. If the content is wider, it is broken into multiple lines and grows vertically.

About eliding you can see this [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34857) which is unresolved.